# I made an ADO.NET Entity, generated from a database but i cant use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

**Sorry for the noob question. im new and i cant figure this out on google.**

The thing is, i used to right click the project go add > new item > ADO.NET Entity 
and then i choose to generate it from database , afterwards i start using it by typing :

```
TheEntityName something = new TheEntityName();
```

but now, for some reason, whenever i type the entity name i get an error that says that it doesnt **exist in the current context** ?

any idea ?

Comment: What is the namespace of the entity class?  What is the namespace of the class in which you're trying to use it?  You may need to add a `using` directive or fully-quality the class name.

Comment: Press `CTRL + .` while clicked on the `TheEntityName`. The dropdown will offer to add a `using` statement for you.

Comment: it didnt work, i got "The type or namespace couldnt be found" error

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the namespace of your entity. Once you know that you have two options. One is adding a using statement in your view

```
@using namespace
```

Or use the fully qualified name...

```
Namespace.entity
```

Comment: But remember, you should use execute database queries in your controller. Pass the result of the query to the view and display them.

Comment: @Leo i still have the same problem, i typed the namespace.entity and it seemed to be okay but whenever i try to run it i get the same error "The type of namespace "modelname" could not be found " , please notice that im using webpages not MVC

Comment: It doesn't matter...you are using razor syntax, right? I assumed you are using webpages with razor. If so, the syntax is the same. Now, what is model name? Can you post the whole class declaration of `TheEntity`? Thanks